# load static pages in android webview

Tags: android, jquery, html, webview

I want to load a static web pages in a webview, so I can use it a website. but the anchor links or redirects is not working, when I click on a link, it won't loaded in the webview, but it will be opened by another HTML viewer app with 404 error. So, simply I want to make each URL to be loaded in the webview.

activity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView wb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wb.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///android_asset/style.css"/>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

                <div class="row">
                    <label for="username">USERNAME</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" class="text-input"/>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="password">PASSWORD</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" class="text-input"/>
                </div>
                <div class="row" id="error"></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <button id="login" class="submit">LOGIN</button>
                </div>
            <a href="file:///android_asset/nearby.html">Next Page</a>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var errors = 0;
                $('#login').click(function(e){
                    if(validate() === 0){
                        if($('#username').val() === 'user' && $('#password').val() === 'pass'){
                            window.location.href = 'file:///android_asset/nearby.html';
                        } else{
                            $('#error').html('username or password is incorrect !').show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                function validate(){
                    checkInput($('#username'));
                    checkInput($('#password'));
                    console.log(errors);
                    return errors;
                };
                function checkInput(element){
                    if(element.val() === ''){
                        element.css('border','2px solid #ff0000');
                        errors++;
                    } else{
                        element.css('border','none');
                        if(errors > 0)
                            errors = errors - 1;
                    }
                };
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

for example, the page should be redirected to `nearby.html` page when the user entered the right values of username and password, but as I said before, the requested page will be opened by another app with a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that you want to handle clicks yourself, by setting the WebView's WebClient. Quoting from the [WebView tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html):

> To open links clicked by the user, simply provide a WebViewClient for
>   your WebView, using setWebViewClient(). For example:

```
  WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
  myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

> That's it. Now all links the user clicks load in your WebView.